# Why is my expected null object not null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a brand new basic mvc application, let say I have a ViewModel Class :

```
public class ViewModel
{
     public string someProp { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my simplified Controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(ViewModel vm = null)
    {
        if (vm == null)
        {
            //Some Debugging Code
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

I run my project (visit [https:localhost:{port}/Home](http://localhost:4654/Home)) and check the vm value inside the index Action using the immediate window view in Visual Studio.

To my biggest surprise, I discover that `vm == null` returns `false`.
I suspected the value to be null since it's the default value.

Can anyone please tell me what Am I missing?

Is a object that has a null proprety not seen as null ?

Comment: What's `vm`'s value ? How does your request look like ?

Comment: the request is something like visiting @Url.Action("Index","Home").
I did vm==null and I got false

Comment: If you're debugging, check what's inside `vm`.

Comment: it is someProp =null

Comment: You can try it, it's not that hard to reproduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never get a null view model even if there are no parameters provided in the request because of how the default model binder works:

1. Instantiate the model
2. Run through all properties of the view model and query the value providers to set values for those properties from the request
3. Return the populated instance

So once your controller action is hit, the view model will never be null.

Answer (score 1):

That is how model binder works.

It tries to create an instance and then sets properties getting values from different sources. It also checks constraints imposed by data annotation attributes, and sets ModelState.IsValid property account accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a value in arguments will not overwrite the argument passed when your `Index(ViewModel)` is called.

When you compile your MVC project, it will automatically instantiate all arguments in your action methods (with `System.Reflection`). I am not sure but with a method similar of `Activator.CreateInstance`. It works only if it can found a proper constructor. And that's why you will get an error if you create a constructor with arguments in your `ViewModel` because it can't find a default constructor to instanciate a `ViewModel` object.

Why this behavior ? `https:localhost:{port}/Home/{id}` => `ActionResult Index(int id) {...}`

**EDIT** A ViewModel has nothing to do in an action method as an argument.

Comment: I dont agree, when I call Index(ViewModel) with arguments it works just fine

Comment: I don't know how you get this but i have a `MissingMethodException`  when `System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance` is invoked (Only if i add a constructor with some arguments).

Comment: I really cant understand what you're talking about, did you try my code ?

Comment: Yes, i started a new project with your code. ViewModel is not null as you said.

Comment: Did you expected to be null as well ?

Comment: Behind all of the ASP framework, there is a lot of work by Reflection. So, this is not surprising. Try this :         `public ViewModel(object test)
        {

        }` as a constructor

Comment: would this make my vm null inside the index action ?

Comment: The code above should launch an error. If you want a view model null, you have to do this in the local context :         `ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)  { model = null; ///...}`.

Comment: not working, because i don't always want it to be null

Comment: You're asking _Why is my expected null object not null?_. I answer you exactly why. And you down vote. Now you're asking another question which looks like _How not instantiate passing arguments in action methods?_. I don't know, there is no reason to do that and this is not a chat.

Comment: I didn't downvote, downvote requires 125 rep which i don't have. Thank you for your answer